# How to change layouts in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a products module in my application which i register at both backend and frontend of my advance application, i want to achieve if a user access the product module from frontend app i want to render a different layout not /myproject/frontend/web/views/layouts/main.php let say i want to render  /myproject/frontend/web/views/layouts/productLayout.php. And if an admin officer access the product module from backend app i want to render /myproject/backend/web/views/layouts/main.php. without changing my code it works perfectly in backend app as it uses /myproject/backend/web/views/layouts/main.php but in front end it don't work good as it uses /myproject/frontend/web/views/layouts/main.php instead of /myproject/backend/web/views/layouts/productLayout.php. i tried this in my code in the products module default controller

```
public $productLayout = '@frontend/views/layouts/productLayout';
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = $this->productLayout;
}
```

and it works perfectly in frontend but when i try to access from backend it doesn't work as it loads the frontend layout file...
any help on this will be good thanks

Comment: seems you need two different layout depending of the application .. ..is this what You need?

Comment: yes i need two different layout one in frontend app depending of the application and the other in backend app depending on the backend app

Comment: I have posted an answer with a  suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the application id (and eventually set it with a proper unique name in config/main.php) and the set the layout you need .

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if (Yii::$app->name  == 'my_id_for_backend') {
     $this->layout == '@backend/views/layouts/main';
    } else {
      $this->layout ='@frontend/views/layouts/productLayout';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it for all actions of a controller with this:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{  
    $this->layout = 'dashboard'; // or  '@app/views/layouts/dashboard'
    return true;
}
```